# Why is regex to match emojis also matching non-emoji symbols ( ' and " ) on mobile?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, I would love help.

I use a regex to detect emojis from a user inputed text. The regex I am using to match emojis is:

```
(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])
```

However, on mobile only, it is also matching various non-emoji symbols including `'` and `"`

I've tried other regex's for emoji matches, but none have been as concise as this one or work as well.

Can anyone help me out?

---

To see the problem live, insert text/emojis/symbols into the Personal Message field (using mobile device): https://2050.cards/shop/birthday/eskimo-surprise/

Example input:

Should not and does not match:

```
Dear you, Happy Birthday.
```

Should match and does match:

```
Dear you , Thanks.
```

Should not BUT DOES match (on mobile only):

```
Dear you, let's all "hang out"
```

Comment: Canyou give some example input? Are you matching text, or single characters?

Comment: @simbabque we create ecards and this is the user inputed message so we are matching text. Up to 125 characters. For example: Dear XXX, Happy Birthday, from YYY. We cannot create cards with emojis in them so disable the Order Card button if a user inserts an emoji. However at the moment if the user is ordering a card on mobile and inserts '  •  " or € then the button is disabled.

Comment: I fixed your post formatting, but I think the Euro sign is missing in your example. I hope I didn't break it.

Comment: Thank you @simbabque for your help 

Comment: I'd expect these characters to be matched. Where are they not matched? E.g. € is U+20AC, which is in `\u2000-\u3300`. See also [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rVbwPE/1).

Comment: @L3viathan thank you I see, how about the ' and the " ? I can do without the € and • as most people do not use them in their messages however the ' and " are used frequently. As a reminder this is only occurring on mobile.

Comment: @BenjyB When I type on that site, `'` and `"` are no problem, it's only after typing `€` that I get the error message.

Comment: Unrelated, but showing the error message about the emoji not being allowed in green is a bit of a usability fail.

Comment: Your regex appears to be matching smart quotes like \u2019. Maybe the mobile device is adding them in.

Comment: @simbabque thanks for the pointer, please could you expand, do you mean that I should display the error message in a different color or in a different way?

Comment: @L3viathan Yes we've only been having this error on mobile.

Comment: @xdhmoore thanks that would explain it. Presume that I could stick with this regex but make some specific exception (u2019, u0027, etc)?

Comment: @BenjyB I like Steven Penny's answer if it's supported for your environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some emojis don't match my Emoji-only regex](/q/57261413/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this, is with [Unicode property escapes](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes).

```
const r = /\p{Emoji}/u;

const a = [
   'Dear you , Thanks. ',
   'Dear you, Happy Birthday.',
   `Dear you, let's all "hang out" • spend some €`
];

for (const s of a) {
   const b = r.test(s);
   console.log(b);
}
```

This is [supported with](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility):

- Chrome 64 (2018)
- Edge 79 (2019)
- Firefox 78 (June 2020)
- Node 10 (2018)
- Safari 11.1 (2018)

Comment: I'm going to start my birthday cards with "Dear you," from now on...

Comment: @xdhmoore make sure to throw in the Emoji: Dear you 

Comment: @StevenPenny I have now implemented this solution and it has worked. Thank you very much for your help on this.